# iMessage and FaceTime won't activate IOS 7

Tags: iphone

Please help, iMessage and FaceTime won't activate after updating my phone to iOS 7. I have tried to be patient... For five days ... I'm about to scratch my eyes out ... Any suggestions I havetried everything people said. Help! -Shay

Answer (score 1):

Attempt to reset your settings via `Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings`. It will not erase your data, but you should have a backup before your attempt it. If the issue persists, "Erase all content and settings" from the same menu, which will erase all of your data. You would have to then restore from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix iOS7 iMessage and FaceTime (phone number) activation issue
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5416934

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.